# I got inputMissMatch exception during my TCS exam

Tags: java

```java
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[])
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            int input1=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            String str1=sc.nextLine();
            Double input2=sc.nextDouble();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code. I only got this exception in "int" and "double" input only in for loop. IF I write it out-side of for loop it working fine. Please any one can help me solve this problem, because I am getting this error in my TCS exam.

Comment: Are you currently in the middle of the exam and is this one of the exam questions?

Comment: "_I only got this exception..._" - what exception?

Comment: *"IF I write it out-side of for loop it working fine."* Nice, problem solved. You're welcome.

Comment: Theres a `{` missing at the end of `public static void main(String args[])`

Comment: Could you add the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question does no give me much information, however I will try to answer anyway (need that rep). Im assuming the issue you run into is a `InputMismatchException` ? This is probably something to do with you trying to pass a `double` (i.e. 12.0) into an `int`. Using something like `System.out.println("Enter Int Input:")` can help you highlight which input type you should be providing on the line.  try/catch blocks can stop the error being thrown.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            System.out.println("Enter Int Value:");
            int input1 = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter String Value:");
            String str1 = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Double Value:");
            Double input2 = sc.nextDouble();
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input entered for variable type.");

    }
}
```